# How can I control the flow of using JavaScript first and then send the control to the back end server created using flask framework?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, flask, linker

I am using Flask Framework..
I have a form tag in the front end for login id and password and a submit button.

I want to use JavaScript in the front end to verify the data provided by the user in the form field and then if everything is okay, then I want to send the data provided by the user to the back end server and process it using python..

**But how can I control the process that when the user click on the submit button the control will go to the JavaScript code and then after validation, the data is sent to the back end server**

In the snippet I have given a dummy example. In that my doubt is how to first send the control to the **validate_login_form()** written in Java Script and then after validation the control should go to the **{{url_for('home')}}** written in the **action** part using the **Jinja2** template engine

Here the trouble that i am having is, **after filling up the form, when the user clicked of the submit button, the control goes fine to the Java Script function written to validate the form but even if the Java Script returns false, the control automatically goes to the back end server.**

**But what i want to do is if the Java Script returns false, the control should stop there and ask the user to again fill in the form.**

```js
function validate_login_form(){
    let login_id = document.getElementById('login_id').value
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value

    if(login_id == '' && password == ''){
        alert('please enter the login id and password')
        return(false)
    }
    else if(login_id == '' && password != ''){
        alert('please enter the login id')
        return(false)
    }
    else if(login_id != '' && password == ''){
        alert('please enter the password')
        return(false)
    }
    else{
        if(login_id == 'test' && password == 'test'){
            return(true);
        }
        else{
            alert('please enter the valid login id and password')
            return(false)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <form action="{{url_for('home')}}" onsubmit="validate_login_form()">
            <label for="login_id">LogIn</label>
            <input type="text" name="login_id" placeholder="login Id" id="login_id">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password">
    
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" >
        </form>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/login.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem here in the codes are in the **form** tag in html,

I should have written **onsubmit=return validate_login_form()**
instead of **onsubmit=validate_login_form()**

By this code if the JavaScript function returns **true** then the page will be redirected to the url written in the **action field of the form tag**
and if the JavaScript function returns **flase** then the control will remain in the same page without being redirected.
That's how the flow can be controlled

```js
function validate_login_form(){
    let login_id = document.getElementById('login_id').value
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value

    if(login_id == '' && password == ''){
        alert('please enter the login id and password')
        return(false)
    }
    else if(login_id == '' && password != ''){
        alert('please enter the login id')
        return(false)
    }
    else if(login_id != '' && password == ''){
        alert('please enter the password')
        return(false)
    }
    else{
        if(login_id == 'test' && password == 'test'){
            return(true);
        }
        else{
            alert('please enter the valid login id and password')
            return(false)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <form action="{{url_for('home')}}" onsubmit="return validate_login_form()">
            <label for="login_id">LogIn</label>
            <input type="text" name="login_id" placeholder="login Id" id="login_id">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password">
    
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" >
        </form>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/login.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp.
There your go:

```
 <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form> 

<script>
function myFunction() {
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: If I do that, when the user click on the submit button, the control will go to JavaScript on frontend, then how will it be sent back to the server after validation?

Comment: When the function returns true, the normal action path will be called

Answer (score 0):

**HTML from example:**

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
myForm.onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    // validate here and produce data


    fetch('/mypage', {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        cache: "no-cache",
        body: data,
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }),
      })
       .then((response) => {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            // handling if status is not ok(200)
          }
          response.text().then((res) => {
            // response handling

            if(res === "success"){
               // redirect to homepage or do anything
            } else {
               // something went wrong
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // error handle
        });
}
```

**Flask/Python:**

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/mypage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myPage():
    if request.method == "POST" and request.json:
          data = request.json
         
          # send data to database

          return 'success', 200
```